# Man pages for Git Bash on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bash, git, man

I am using Git bash on Windows 7. It provides me with a way to use most of the commands that I used to use on the bash shell on my Ubuntu machine. But the man and the info commands do not work. Is there a way to get these (incredible) documentation commands working on the Git bash shell on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the online documentation.

[Linux man pages online](http://man.he.net/) & [GNU Info Pages](http://www.gnu.org/manual/manual.html)

Comment: are there any programs that will connect to these web pages from the command line and display the result? so that I can still type info grep on the shell and get the results there?

Comment: @Prasanth perhaps you can do a wget <URL> & then grep it.

Comment: or he could do this `curl "http://man.he.net/?topic=<command_name>&section=all"`. replace the `<command_name>` with the command you're looking for

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question; he wants these commands to work in the shell.

Answer (score 9):

I have stitched together some of the other answers to get a `man` command you can use like you would natively. Just stick the following in your `.bashrc`, and either `source` it, or re-open your terminal.

```bsh
function man {
    local section=all
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then section="$1"; shift; fi
    local doc="$(curl -v --silent --data-urlencode topic="$@" --data-urlencode section="$section" http://man.he.net/ 2>&1)"
    local ok=$?
    local pre="$(printf '%s' "$doc" | sed -ne "/<PRE>/,/<\/PRE>/ { /<PRE>/ { n; b; }; p }")"
    [[ $ok -eq 0 && -n "$pre" ]] && printf '%s' "$pre" | less || printf 'Got nothing.\n' >&2
    return $ok
}
```

It also supports requesting particular man sections, for example `man 3 printf` for the system call.

**Weaknesses:** The source (man.he.net) isn't exactly a RESTful API, and it returns 200 even when nothing is found, so it's hard to give accurate error messages. Instead, this just prints "Got nothing", no matter what the problem was. This can probably be improved. Also, the resulting page contains html entities, such as `&lt;` instead of `<`, which makes some usage strings ugly.

Comment: Best answer.  Thank you!  It works.

Answer (score 8):

You **can** get man pages working on Git's bash environment, but it's probably more convenient to consider other alternatives that take less work.

I also don't have much rep on SuperUser, so I'm sad to say I can't really give all the links I need to in the response. I [re-posted my response](http://bitsandnucleotides.tumblr.com/post/58929593915/response-to-the-question-man-pages-for-git-bash-on) on Tumblr.

In summary:

- Git's bash is a part of the msysGit project.
- msysGit is a fork of the MinGW and MSYS project
- You'll need either msysGit or MinGW to install MinGW-get
- You'll need MinGW-get to install Groff
- You'll need Groff to run these [scripts](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/ManScript) to give you a man command from within the msys bash shell
- With those scripts in place, you can read man pages. You'll just need to download them to the path you've indicated in the scripts.

Good luck.

Comment: You can install man with `MinGW-get install msys-man`. Man is also available as a windows binary: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/ (found via the FAQ: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ#toc10). That page also has groff. Either would probably run faster than those scripts.

Comment: @SamHasler msys-man is great. Thanks for the tip, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

It may be a bit overkill, but you could download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) which would include `bash`, `man`, and info readers like `pinfo`.

The cygwin installer would let you customize your install to be a pretty small subset of cygwin.

Comment: Not overkill in the slightest; it seems fairly common that someone will want a Unixy experience on Windows and install Git Bash mistakenly thinking that's the way to get one. Cygwin, meanwhile, actually provides one, probably to the maximal extent possible or very nearly so.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Sathya's answer](https://superuser.com/a/295409/253569), you could also do this in bash for Windows:

```
curl -v --silent "http://man.he.net/?topic=<command_name>&section=all" 2>&1 | sed -n "/<PRE>/,/<\/PRE>/p"
```

Just replace the `<command_name>` with the command you're looking for.

Example output for the command `ls`:

> <PRE> SYNOPSIS
>          ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          List  information  about  the FILEs (the current directory by default).
>          Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort  is  speci-
>          fied.
>
> ```
>    Mandatory  arguments  to  long  options are mandatory for short options
>    too.
>
>    -a, --all
>           do not ignore entries starting with .
>
>    -A, --almost-all
>           do not list implied . and ..
>
>    --author
>           with -l, print the author of each file
>
>    -b, --escape
>           print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters
>
>    --block-size=SIZE
>           scale   sizes   by   SIZE   before   printing    them.     E.g.,
>           `--block-size=M'  prints sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes.  See
>           SIZE format below.
>
>    -B, --ignore-backups
>           do not list implied entries ending with ~
>
>    -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of
>           file  status  information)  with -l: show ctime and sort by name
>           otherwise: sort by ctime, newest first
>
>    -C     list entries by columns
>
>    --color[=WHEN]
>           colorize the output.   WHEN  defaults  to  `always'  or  can  be
>           `never' or `auto'.  More info below
>
>    -d, --directory
>           list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer-
>           ence symbolic links
>
>    -D, --dired
>           generate output designed for Emacs' dired mode
>
>    -f     do not sort, enable -aU, disable -ls --color
>
>    -F, --classify
>           append indicator (one of */=&gt;@|) to entries
>
>    --group-directories-first
>           group directories before files.
>
>           augment  with  a  --sort option, but any use of --sort=none (-U)
>           disables grouping
>
>    -G, --no-group
>           in a long listing, don't print group names
>
>    -h, --human-readable
>           with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
>
>    --si   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024
>
>    -H, --dereference-command-line
>           follow symbolic links listed on the command line
>
>    --dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir
>           follow each command line symbolic link that points to  a  direc-
>           tory
>
>    --hide=PATTERN
>           do  not  list implied entries matching shell PATTERN (overridden
>           by -a or -A)
>
>    --indicator-style=WORD
>           append indicator with style WORD to entry names: none (default),
>           slash (-p), file-type (--file-type), classify (-F)
>
>    -i, --inode
>           print the index number of each file
>
>    -I, --ignore=PATTERN
>           do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN
>
>    -k     like --block-size=1K
>
>    -l     use a long listing format
>
>    -L, --dereference
>           when showing file information for a symbolic link, show informa-
>           tion for the file the link references rather than for  the  link
>           itself
>
>    -m     fill width with a comma separated list of entries
>
>    -n, --numeric-uid-gid
>           like -l, but list numeric user and group IDs
>
>    -N, --literal
>           print  raw entry names (don't treat e.g. control characters spe-
>           cially)
>
>    -o     like -l, but do not list group information
>           enclose entry names in double quotes
>
>    --quoting-style=WORD
>           use  quoting style WORD for entry names: literal, locale, shell,
>           shell-always, c, escape
>
>    -r, --reverse
>           reverse order while sorting
>
>    -R, --recursive
>           list subdirectories recursively
>
>    -s, --size
>           print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
>
>    -S     sort by file size
>
>    --sort=WORD
>           sort by WORD instead of name: none -U, extension  -X,  size  -S,
>           time -t, version -v
>
>    --time=WORD
>           with  -l,  show time as WORD instead of modification time: atime
>           -u, access -u, use -u, ctime -c, or  status  -c;  use  specified
>           time as sort key if --sort=time
>
>    --time-style=STYLE
>           with  -l, show times using style STYLE: full-iso, long-iso, iso,
>           locale, +FORMAT.  FORMAT is interpreted like `date';  if  FORMAT
>           is  FORMAT1&lt;newline&gt;FORMAT2, FORMAT1 applies to non-recent files
>           and FORMAT2 to recent files; if STYLE is prefixed with `posix-',
>           STYLE takes effect only outside the POSIX locale
>
>    -t     sort by modification time, newest first
>
>    -T, --tabsize=COLS
>           assume tab stops at each COLS instead of 8
>
>    -u     with  -lt:  sort  by, and show, access time with -l: show access
>           time and sort by name otherwise: sort by access time
>
>    -U     do not sort; list entries in directory order
>
>    -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
>
>    -w, --width=COLS
>           assume screen width instead of current value
>
>    -x     list entries by lines instead of by columns
>
>    -X     sort alphabetically by entry extension
>
>    -Z, --context
>           print any SELinux security context of each file
>
>    Using color to distinguish file types is disabled both by  default  and
>    with  --color=never.  With --color=auto, ls emits color codes only when
>    standard output is connected to a terminal.  The LS_COLORS  environment
>    variable can change the settings.  Use the dircolors command to set it.
> ```
>
> Exit status:
>          0      if OK,
>
> ```
>    1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),
>
>    2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
> ```
>
> AUTHOR
>          Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
>
> REPORTING BUGS
>          Report ls bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
>          GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/&gt;
>          General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/&gt;
>          Report ls translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/&gt;
>
> COPYRIGHT
>          Copyright  (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  License GPLv3+: GNU
>          GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html&gt;.
>          This is free software: you are free  to  change  and  redistribute  it.
>          There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> SEE ALSO
>          The  full  documentation  for ls is maintained as a Texinfo manual.  If
>          the info and ls programs are properly installed at your site, the  com-
>          mand
>
> ```
>           info coreutils 'ls invocation'
>
>    should give you access to the complete manual.
> ```
>
> GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb    September 2011
>   <STRONG><A HREF="/man1/LS">LS(1)</A></STRONG></PRE>

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498045/gitbash-command-quick-reference/31636480#31636480), from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498045/gitbash-command-quick-reference), might be helpful:

Gives you info for the command right in the bash window.

> Git command Quick Reference
>
> `git [command] -help`

Opens the online info for the command in your browser.

> Git command Manual Pages
>
> ```
> git help [command]
> git [command] --help
> ```

Comment: In the future it will be expected you cite and quote the relevant information when you provide a link.  You should also learn how to properly format your answers.

Comment: This appears to only be for Git commands.  These are not necessarily the same as their non-git counterparts.  For instance `git grep` does not support the `-R` option. https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_git_commands

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is trying to get `man` to work on Windows and is using **Msys2**, here is what I found:

I got very close by using the [answer above](https://superuser.com/a/634889/279136) which says to install `groff` (available via pacman) and then use the [script here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/ManScript), which has at its core the call to `groff -Tascii -mandoc -P-c`.

But I could not get it to work on my man pages (found in `/usr/share/man`) *unless I uncompressed the gz files first*!

This was not an acceptable solution, so I looked further and found that by running

```
pacman -Ss -man
```

that there are three packages (currently) that have the prefix of "man-".  ([see them here](https://github.com/alexpux/msys2-packages)).

I tried the one called **man-db**, it works, and now I have ability to run `man` in the regular expected fashion.

Comment: Today I am able to simply run `pacman -S man` and install proceeds as expected

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the end of `.bashrc`

`C:\Users\<Username>\.bashrc`

```
function man() {
    VAR1="http://man.he.net/?topic="
    VAR2=$1
    VAR3="&section=all"
    VAR4="$VAR1$VAR2$VAR3"
    curl -v --silent "$VAR4" 2>&1 | sed -n "/<PRE>/,/<\/PRE>/p"
}
```

---

Add it to the end of `.bash_profile`

`C:\Users\<Username>\.bash_profile`

```
# Read .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Restart terminal.

`man find` will return the manual pages for `find`.

---

Here is a version for really short answer:

```
function man-short() {
    $1 --help
}
```